# PhysicsBody covers half of sprite

Tags: sprite-kit

PhysicsBody added only to half of a sprite

[image]

I have add a sprite to a `GameScene` and set a Body type in Physics Definitions to `Alpha` mask.

Then I want to check if I've clicked on physics body or not. 
But, it shows **yes** only when I click on green area.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walking_walking_2")
    let wallS = SKSpriteNode (texture: texture)
    wallS.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
    wallS.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.addChild(wallS)
    view.showsPhysics = true
}

override func touchesBegan (_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        touchLocation = t.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation!)
        if (touchedNode?.categoryBitMask == 1)
        {
            print("yes")
        } else {
            print ("no")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ll have to post your code that creates both the sprite and the physicsBody.

Comment: I've tried to do it with code and directly in SpriteKit Editor

Comment: I have found another solution. I enumerate through all physicsBody and check if there is one, with needed categoryBitMask

self.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(at: touchLocation) {body,stop in
                
                if (body.categoryBitMask == 1)
                {
                    print ("yes")
                }
            }